# UITableView Navigation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following hierarchy in my app but the navigation controller isn't working. When I go back up the hierarchy in the storyboard, the higher level tableview controllers are blank instead of showing the previous view.

```
UITabBarController
        UINavigationController
                UITableViewController
                UITableViewController
                DetailViewController
```

Here's my code for the TableView Controller

```
@interface ExerciseTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation ExerciseTableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addExercise:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = add;

    NSLog(@"level: %i, currentSMID: %i, currentMID: %i", _level, _currentSMID, _currentMID);

    if (self.managedObjectContext_ == nil) {
        self.managedObjectContext_ = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }

    if (_level == 1) {
        _submuscleNameArray = [self submuscleGroup:_currentMID valueForKeyPath:@"submuscleGroup"];
        _submuscleIDArray = [self submuscleGroup:_currentMID valueForKeyPath:@"submuscleID"];
    } else if (_level == 2) {
        //loading and sorting exercise list
        _exerciseList = [self loadExercise:_currentMID sub:_currentSMID];
        _exerciseListSorted = [self sortKeysByName];
    } else {
        [self loadMuscleGroup];
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSInteger count;

    if (_level == 0) {
        count = [_muscleNameArray count];
    } else if (_level == 1) {
        count = [_submuscleNameArray count];
    } else {
        count = [_exerciseList count];
    }

    return count;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_level == 0) {
        int muscleID = [_muscleIDArray[indexPath.row] intValue];
        NSLog(@"MuscleID: %i", muscleID);
        NSArray *submuscleArray = [self submuscleGroup:muscleID valueForKeyPath:@"submuscleID"];
        if (submuscleArray == nil || [submuscleArray count] == 0) {

            _currentMID = muscleID;
            _level = 2;
            _detailTitle = _muscleNameArray[indexPath.row];
                    NSLog(@"title: %@", _detailTitle);
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"drillDown2" sender:self];
        } else {
            _currentMID = muscleID;
            _level = 1;
            _detailTitle = _muscleNameArray[indexPath.row];
                    NSLog(@"title: %@", _detailTitle);
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"drillDown" sender:self];
        }

    } else if (_level == 1) {

        _level = 2;
        _currentSMID = [_submuscleIDArray[indexPath.row] intValue];
        _detailTitle = _submuscleNameArray[indexPath.row];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"drillDown2" sender:self];

    } else {
        _detailTitle = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:0];
        _equipment = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:1];
        _image = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:2];
        _imageNumber =  [[[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
        _levelString = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:4];
        _status = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:5];
        _thumbnail = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:6];
        _type = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:7];
        _unitOfMeasure = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:8];
        _video = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:9];
        _workoutDirections = [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:10];
        _exerciseID = [[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showExerciseDetail" sender:self];

    }


}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"drillDownCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (_level == 0) {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[_muscleNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else if (_level == 1) {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[_submuscleNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else {
        [[cell textLabel] setText:[[_exerciseList valueForKey:[_exerciseListSorted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }

    return cell;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return nil;
}


#pragma mark - 
#pragma Data Retrieval methods

-(NSArray *) sortKeysByName{

    //Method of NSDictionary class which sorts the keys using the logic given by the comparator block
    NSArray * sortArray = [_exerciseList keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

        //We do case insensitive comparision of two strings as we are not really concerned about
        //the "content" of the strings (please see sortKeysOnTheBasisOfNationalIncome method where
        //we would like to do the comparision with numeric search as an extra option)
        NSComparisonResult result = [[obj1 objectAtIndex:0] caseInsensitiveCompare:[obj2 objectAtIndex:0]];
        return result;
    }];

    //Show Result in the Output Panel
    for (int i = 0; i < [sortArray count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"WorkoutID:%@, WorkoutName:%@",[sortArray objectAtIndex:i], [[_exerciseList valueForKey:[sortArray objectAtIndex:i]] objectAtIndex:0]);
    }

    return sortArray;
}

- (void)loadMuscleGroup{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    //this is needed because QuizViewController isn't the first level view. The managedObjectContext was nil before this declaration
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Muscle_Group"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext_];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    _muscleArray = [[_managedObjectContext_ executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    NSSortDescriptor *muscleSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"muscleGroup" ascending:YES];
    [_muscleArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:muscleSort]];
    _muscleNameArray = [_muscleArray valueForKeyPath:@"muscleGroup"];
    _muscleIDArray = [_muscleArray valueForKeyPath:@"muscleID"];
//    NSLog(@"muscleIDArray count:%i, muscleNameArray count:%i, muscleID1: %d, muscleID2: %d", [_muscleIDArray count], [_muscleNameArray count], _muscleIDArray[1], _muscleIDArray[2]);
}

- (NSArray *)submuscleGroup:(int)muscleID valueForKeyPath:(NSString *)string{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    //this is needed because QuizViewController isn't the first level view. The managedObjectContext was nil before this declaration
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SubMuscle_Group"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext_];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"muscleID = %i", muscleID];
    NSLog(@"muscleID = %i", muscleID);
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *submuscleArray = [[_managedObjectContext_ executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    NSSortDescriptor *submuscleSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"submuscleGroup" ascending:YES];
    [submuscleArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:submuscleSort]];
    NSArray *submuscleGroupArray = [submuscleArray valueForKeyPath:string];
    return submuscleGroupArray;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)loadExercise:(int)muscleID sub:(int)subMuscleID{

    //Getting Array from Workout Muscle Relationship Table
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Workout_Muscle_Relationship"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext_];
    NSPredicate *predicate;
    if (subMuscleID != 0) {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"muscleID = %i AND submuscleID = %i", muscleID, subMuscleID];
    } else {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"muscleID = %i", muscleID];
    }

    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *workoutRelationshipArray = [[_managedObjectContext_ executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    NSSortDescriptor *workoutSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"workoutID" ascending:YES];
    [workoutRelationshipArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:workoutSort]];
    NSArray *workoutIDArray = [workoutRelationshipArray valueForKeyPath:@"workoutID"];


    //Getting Array from Workout Group Table
    NSFetchRequest *request2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity2 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Workout_Group_Table"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext_];
    [request2 setEntity:entity2];
    NSMutableArray *workoutArray = [[_managedObjectContext_ executeFetchRequest:request2 error:&error] mutableCopy];
    NSSortDescriptor *workoutSort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"workoutID" ascending:YES];
    [workoutArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:workoutSort2]];
    NSArray *workoutIDArray2 = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"workoutID"];
    NSArray *workoutName = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"workoutName"];
    NSArray *equipmentArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"equipment"];
    NSArray *imageArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"image"];
    NSArray *imageNumberArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"imageNumber"];
    NSArray *levelStringArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"level"];
    NSArray *statusArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"status"];
    NSArray *thumbnailArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"thumbnail"];
    NSArray *typeArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"type"];
    NSArray *unitOfMeasureArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"unitOfMeasure"];
    NSArray *videoArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"video"];
    NSArray *workoutDirectionsArray = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"workoutDirections"];
    NSArray *workoutID = [workoutArray valueForKeyPath:@"workoutID"];
    NSArray *muscleImageArray = [workoutArray valueForKey:@"muscleImage"];

    NSMutableDictionary *list = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    NSLog(@"workoutIDArray count: %i, workoutIDArray2 count: %i", [workoutIDArray count], [workoutIDArray2 count]);
    int start = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [workoutIDArray count]; i ++) {
        NSLog(@"i:%i", i);
        for (int j = start; j < [workoutIDArray2 count]; j++) {
            NSLog(@"j:%i",j);
            if (workoutIDArray[i] == workoutIDArray2[j]) {
                NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:workoutName[j], equipmentArray[j], imageArray[j], imageNumberArray[j], levelStringArray[j], statusArray[j], thumbnailArray[j], typeArray[j], unitOfMeasureArray[j], videoArray[j], workoutDirectionsArray[j], workoutID[j], muscleImageArray[j], nil];
                NSString *temp2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", workoutIDArray2[j]];
                [list setValue:temp forKey:temp2];
                start = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }



    return list;

}

- (NSString *)getExerciseInfo:(int)eid valueForKeyPah:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *result;



    return result;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showExerciseDetail"]) {
        //ExerciseDetail *exerciseDetail = (ExerciseDetail *)segue.destinationViewController;
        //exerciseDetail.pageTitle = detailTitle;
        //UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        ExerciseDetail *exerciseDetail = (ExerciseDetail *)segue.destinationViewController;
        exerciseDetail.title = _detailTitle;
        exerciseDetail.exerciseID = _exerciseID;
        exerciseDetail.imageNumber = _imageNumber;
        exerciseDetail.image = _image;
        exerciseDetail.equipment = _equipment;
        exerciseDetail.levelString = _levelString;
        exerciseDetail.status = _status;
        exerciseDetail.thumbnail = _thumbnail;
        exerciseDetail.type = _type;
        exerciseDetail.unitOfMeasure = _unitOfMeasure;
        exerciseDetail.video = _video;
        exerciseDetail.workoutDirections = _workoutDirections;
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"drillDown"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"drillDown2"]){
        //UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        ExerciseTableViewController *tableView = segue.destinationViewController;
        tableView.title = _detailTitle;
        NSLog(@"title: %@", _detailTitle);
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.level = _level;
        tableView.currentSMID = _currentSMID;
        tableView.currentMID = _currentMID;
        tableView.muscleNameArray = _muscleNameArray;
        if (_level == 2) {
            tableView.submuscleNameArray = _submuscleNameArray;
        }
        NSLog(@"level: %i, currentSMID: %i, currentMID: %i", _level, _currentSMID, _currentMID);
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addExercise"]){
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        AddExerciseViewController *addExercise = (AddExerciseViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        addExercise.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;    
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"dismissView"]){
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)addExercise:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addExercise" sender:sender];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"muscleNameArray count: %i, submuscleNameArray count: %i, exercistList count: %i", [_muscleNameArray count], [_submuscleNameArray count], [_exerciseList count]);
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.myWorkoutList reloadData];
    NSLog(@"muscleNameArray count: %i, submuscleNameArray count: %i, exercistList count: %i", [_muscleNameArray count], [_submuscleNameArray count], [_exerciseList count]);
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Did you check if "muscleNameArray", "submuscleNameArray" and "exerciseList" are not nil when you return?

Comment: You don't need to @synthesize for the past 3 years.

Comment: Fogmeister, I've updated and removed all the @synthesize, no help.

Teddy, I checked and all arrays are not nil. They have data. I can drill down no problem. All data is displayed but when I go back up, it's all blank.

Comment: Should I put any of my code in the viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear?